# How to re-use namespaced library classes without namespacing my own code?

Tags: php, namespaces

When writing library code it is a well-known good practice to namespace it to prevent from potential naming conflicts. But is it a good thing to force my library users to add namespaces to their code as well? (It is not my job to force someone to do things i prever! I want everyone to judge on its own.)

Is there an option for those user to re-use my library code without being forced to namespace own code?

As far as i can see:

```
use com\vendor\library\libname;
```

(alone) do not work. A "namespace" statement is required to combine it with the "use" statement.

But to declare own code in global space with:

```
namespace;
use com\vendor\library\libname;
```

or

```
namespace \;
use com\vendor\library\libname;
```

is not allowed.
It has to be (e.g.):

```
namespace my\own\code\namespace;
use com\vendor\library\libname;
```

Should i release my lib in a namespaced version and a non-namespaced version to not force my users to use namespaces.? How to circumstance the viral effect?

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that it "do not work"? It work just fine.

Comment: I missed the fact that it should be "use com\vendor\library\libname\classname;" to work. I did realised that i missed "classname".

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to namespace their own code to use your namespaced classes.
They can just either `use` your class:

```
use com\vendor\library\libname;

$lib = libname();
echo $lib->showKittens();
```

Or just initialize it with the full namespace:

```
$lib = com\vendor\library\libname();
echo $lib->showKittens();
```